# Class-validator. Make all fields of the parent class optional

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-validator

I have a DTO to create a product

```
export class CreateProductDto {
  @IsString()
  title!: string

  @IsString()
  description!: string

  @IsString()
  url!: string

  @IsNumber()
  @Min(0)
  price!: number

  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @Type(() => ImageDto)
  images!: ImageDto[]

  @IsArray()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @ArrayMinSize(1)
  @Type(() => ProductSizeDto)
  sizes!: ProductSizeDto[]
}
```

I need a DTO for a product update. To avoid repeating myself I inherit from the creation dto. But I need all fields of the parent class to become @IsOptional()

```
export class UpdateProductDto extends CreateProductDto {
  @IsString()
  id!: string;
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How to add fields from CreateProductDto in the UpdateProductDto class @IsOptional()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a use case for [`PartialType` from `@nestjs/mapped-types`](https://github.com/nestjs/mapped-types). You would be able to do something like

```
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/mapped-types';

export class UpdateProductDto extends PartialType(CreateProductDto) {
  @IsString()
  id!: string;
}
```

If you are using `@nestjs/swagger` you can import `PartialType` from `@nestjs/swagger` instead to keep the OpenAPI metadata for the `UpdateProductsDto`, as it extends the initial implementation of `@nestjs/mapped-types`

Comment: Now I get an error when building my project  "Module not found: Can't resolve 'class-transformer/storage'" - class-transformer/storage is referenced here "../../node_modules/@nestjs/mapped-types/dist/type-helpers.utils.js"